# Best Method of Embedding 100+ Videos on a Single Page

Tags: javascript, performance, video, iframe

Our school produces videos and live streamed sports events. We are trying to figure out the best way of having all of our videos and streams (both live and recorded) all in one place. We host our streams on livestream.com and our videos are typically put onto Google Drive. Our CMS (finalsite) allows us to add plenty of organization. We have a tab for each school year, and under each tab we have a list of categories (football, hockey, etc). Clicking one will expand it's content. Adding in every video in this method is what we want because it makes using it easy. In practice, it's horribly slow because of all of the iframe embeds. I've tried having a static image that you can click to bring up the iframe but our CMS doesn't like it, so it doesn't work. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Simple answer is : you don't. Have that site image direct the user to +"/videourl" where you show single video.

Comment: You're streaming a lot of data. Sure, there are optimization techniques, but strapping jet engines to a million-pound vehicle doesn't mean you're going to get it into space. Too much weight; you're streaming too much data.

Comment: What do you mean by "our CMS doesn't like it"?   What is the content of the iframes?  Can you post some code / html?